# WPF nested datagrid for custom data structure

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a custom data structure and I need a WPF component which will represent my data structure. Component should look like on a picture. Component should be dynamic, so number of ColumnSets in structure can be from 1 to x. And each columnSet can have different count of Columns.

```
public class CustomStructure{
   public List<ColumnSet> ColumnSets{get; set;}
}   

public class ColumnSet{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Column> ColumnSets{get;}
}

public class Column{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<int> Data{get;}
}
```

First row represent Name property from class ColumnSet. Second row is a Name property from class Column. Other rows are Data from Column class.

[Wanted WPF component design (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyxJJ.png)

**My Solution**

I defined two components. First represent outer table, and it is called FuzzyTableControl. It has X columns and only ONE row.
Second represent FuzzyInnerTableControl for each column in first row of FuzzyTableControl.

FuzzyTableControl.xaml

```
 <UserControl:Class="FuzzyTableControl">       
   <UserControl.DataContext>
       <viewModel:FuzzyTableViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}">
// here is problem 1
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <view:FuzzyInnerTableControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

FuzzyTableViewModel.cs

```
public class FuzzyTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public FuzzyTable Table { get; set; }

        public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }


        public FuzzyTableViewModel()
        {
            Table = FuzzyTable.Generate(3, 2);
            DataTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (var attribute in Table.Attributes)
            {
                DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(attribute.Name));
            }
            var row = new List<object>();
            foreach (var attribute in Table.Attributes)
                row.Add(attribute);

            DataTable.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

FuzzyInnerTableControl.xaml
this one works good

```
 <UserControl:Class="FuzzyInnerTableControl">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:FuzzyInnerTableViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>    
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"/>
</UserControl>
```

FuzzyInnerTableViewModel.cs

```
public class FuzzyInnerTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public DataTable DataTable { get; }

        public ColumnSetDouble ColumnSetDouble { get; set; }

        public FuzzyInnerTableViewModel()
        {
            // test
            var table = FuzzyTable.Generate(3, 2);
            ColumnSetDouble = table.ClassAttribute;
            //end test

            DataTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (var attribute in ColumnSetDouble.Columns)
                DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(attribute.Name));

            for (int rowId = 0; rowId < ColumnSetDouble.Columns[0].Data.Count; rowId++)
            {
                var row = new List<object>();
                foreach (var column in ColumnSetDouble.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(column.Data[rowId]);
                }

                DataTable.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
            }

        }

    }
```

I don't know how to define cell template for each column of FuzzyTableControl. This solution creates NEW column, but I need load columns dynamically from viewModel.

Comment: A DataGrid is typically represented by a row-collection where each row has some column properties. You may want to convert your data into a row-based structure before trying to display.

Comment: If you want to know how to display multiple tables, you should already know how to display a single table (one `ColumnSet`) and include it in your question. Otherwise you should first figure out how to display a single table and not worry about many tables. The question is to broad as it is.

Comment: I just added more details to question.

Comment: Can you change your code classes so that the names you use in XAML and the names in code are matching? Can't really translate between all your `ColumnSets` in code and `{Binding DataTable}`, `FuzzyInnerTableControl` and so on in xaml.

Comment: I added code behind. Sorry, I forget before.

Comment: One more question: is there a real reason to have the inner tables nested in a table? It would probably be easier to generate a list of tables instead of having a table where each column is a table and there is only one row (strong hint against using a table)

Comment: Yes many reasons, when you need resize Column A2 for example, all subcolumns A2,1 A2,2, ... A2,N will be resized too. Look at the picture, first 2 rows must be headers. Data starts at third row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to define the template for all auto-generated cells, you can try using the `DataGrid.CellStyle`.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <view:FuzzyInnerTableControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

If I have a better idea I'll edit.

---

Now you ask why `<view:FuzzyInnerTableControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>` is not working. So I suppose you have prepared your outer DataTable so it really contains the `FuzzyInnerTableViewModel` which is not completely trivial:

```
// when creating a column, ensure to set the DataType, so your content won't be reduced to some text
DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(attribute.Name, typeof(FuzzyInnerTableViewModel)));

// I have no idea what attribute is, but it better be a FuzzyInnerTableViewModel for your use case!
row.Add(attribute);
```

First of all, the `DataGrid` will try to auto generate relatively useless `DataGridTextColumn`, which needs to be changed. Handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event in order to change the column type. The `DataGridTemplateColumn` will not actually provide you with the cell content **and** if you (like me) try to set the `DataGridCell.Content` via `CellStyle`, it will kindly ignore you and set the content locally instead. So lets push the cell value to `DataGridCell.Tag` for the time being.

Here is `FuzzyTableControl` with the `DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn` method that is connected to the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event in xaml.

```
public partial class FuzzyTableControl : UserControl
{
    public FuzzyTableControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell))
            {
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter(DataGridCell.TagProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName)),
                }
            },
            Header = e.Column.Header,
            HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
            HeaderStyle = e.Column.HeaderStyle,
            HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
            HeaderTemplateSelector = e.Column.HeaderTemplateSelector,
            // transfer whatever properties you feel worthy in your scenario
        };
    }
}
```

Now, at least the desired data are hanging around somewhere in the `Tag`, but guess what - the `DataGrid.CellStyle` was just replaced by a style who's main concern is to dynamically bind some data. So lets move the `DataTemplate` into the resources and add the binding to some parent `DataGridCell.Tag` while its hot...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FuzzyInnerTableTemplate">
        <view:FuzzyInnerTableControl
            DataContext="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and wire up the template with all the other things inside column generation for the `DataGridTemplateColumn`

```
            // ...
            // transfer whatever properties you feel worthy in your scenario
            CellTemplate = Resources["FuzzyInnerTableTemplate"] as DataTemplate
```

Remove the `UserControl.DataContext` from `FuzzyInnerTableControl`, because otherwise the binding will fail miserably and you still get the default values. Find some other approach if you need to combine default and outside-provided values.

---

Confused? Well, so was I, so here's the summary of my testing code, including some made-up rows and columns, since I don't have your whole `Column.Data` and `Table.Attributes` stuff available:

XAML for FuzzyTable (Control, ViewModel)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.FuzzyTableControl"
             ...
    >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:FuzzyTableViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FuzzyInnerTableTemplate">
            <view:FuzzyInnerTableControl
                DataContext="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"
        AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Code for FuzzyTable

```
public partial class FuzzyTableControl : UserControl
{
    public FuzzyTableControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell))
            {
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter(DataGridCell.TagProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName)),
                }
            },
            Header = e.Column.Header,
            HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
            HeaderStyle = e.Column.HeaderStyle,
            HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
            HeaderTemplateSelector = e.Column.HeaderTemplateSelector,
            // transfer whatever properties you feel worthy in your scenario
            CellTemplate = Resources["FuzzyInnerTableTemplate"] as DataTemplate
        };
    }
}

public class FuzzyTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }


    public FuzzyTableViewModel()
    {
        DataTable = new DataTable();

        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("O", typeof(FuzzyInnerTableViewModel)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("P", typeof(FuzzyInnerTableViewModel)));

        var c1 = new FuzzyInnerTableViewModel();
        var c2 = new FuzzyInnerTableViewModel();

        c1.DataTable.Rows[1][0] = "Replace";

        var row = new List<object>();
        row.Add(c1);
        row.Add(c2);

        DataTable.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
    }
}
```

XAML for FuzzyInnerTable

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.FuzzyInnerTableControl"
             ...
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewModel:FuzzyInnerTableViewModel x:Key="defaultVM"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code for FuzzyInnerTable

```
public partial class FuzzyInnerTableControl : UserControl
{
    public FuzzyInnerTableControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            DataContext = Resources["defaultVM"];
        }

    }
}

public class FuzzyInnerTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public DataTable DataTable { get; private set; }

    public FuzzyInnerTableViewModel()
    {
        DataTable = new DataTable();

        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A"));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("B"));

        for (int rowId = 0; rowId < 3; rowId++)
        {
            var row = new List<object>();
            row.Add(rowId);
            row.Add(2 * rowId);

            DataTable.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Just one more question. In row I created new  FuzzyInnerTableViewModel and I want to bind it. But this code doesn't work <view:FuzzyInnerTableControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>

Comment: @Patrik "Doesn't work" is a pretty vague problem description. Is it throwing an error, is it logging something to the debugger output, is it not showing (if so, what does Snoop or a similar WPF runtime debugger tell about the available datacontext?)

Comment: New data are not updated, it is still showing default data. In snoop on data context tab there is default ViewModel.

Comment: @Patrik wow it's really getting super ugly, since the DataGrid doesn't bother to provide the cell content for anything like a useful utilization. On top of that, your approach of setting the `UserControl.DataContext` is interfering with the binding, so I'll have to hack around a lot of shitty details for something that should be easy...